# SQL Server Query - Create New Events to Fill Gaps

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with event data containing columns:

- Asset: name of asset
- StartDate: start date of event
- EndDate: end date of event
- Code: code given to event
- Reason: reason given to event

See below for example

[image]

I need to fill the gaps between the events with a new event (with given code and reason value), specific to individual assets.  The events need to lapse to a given end date.  See below for the result where the end date is 2017-01-02 20:00

[image]

My SQL skills are not bad but this is beyond me.  Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
  DECLARE @t TABLE(
    Asset nvarchar(100),
    StartDate datetime,
    EndDate datetime,
    Code nvarchar(100),
    Reason nvarchar(100)
  );

  DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2017-01-01 00:00:00';
  DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2017-01-02 20:00:00';

  INSERT INTO @t VALUES  ('Asset 1', '2017-01-01 06:00:00', '2017-01-01 09:00:00', 'Code 1', 'Reason 1')
                        ,('Asset 1', '2017-01-01 15:00:00', '2017-01-01 16:00:00', 'Code 1', 'Reason 2')
                        ,('Asset 1', '2017-01-02 12:00:00', '2017-01-02 13:00:00', 'Code 2', 'Reason 2')
                        ,('Asset 2', '2017-01-01 07:00:00', '2017-01-01 08:00:00', 'Code 1', 'Reason 1')
                        ,('Asset 2', '2017-01-01 11:00:00', '2017-01-01 14:00:00', 'Code 1', 'Reason 2')
                        ,('Asset 2', '2017-01-02 15:00:00', '2017-01-02 18:00:00', 'Code 2', 'Reason 2')
                        ,('Asset 2', '2017-01-02 18:00:00', '2017-01-02 19:00:00', 'Code 2', 'Reason 2');

  WITH cte AS(
    SELECT *
          ,EndDate AS StartDateNew
          ,ISNULL(LEAD(StartDate) OVER (PARTITION BY Asset ORDER BY StartDate), @EndDate) AS EndDateNew
          ,CASE WHEN EndDate = LEAD(StartDate) OVER (PARTITION BY Asset ORDER BY StartDate) OR EndDate = @EndDate THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS HasGap
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Asset ORDER BY StartDate) AS rn
      FROM @t t
    WHERE StartDate >= @StartDate
  )
  SELECT Asset, StartDate, EndDate, Code, Reason
    FROM cte
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Asset, StartDateNew, EndDateNew, 'Code10', 'Reason10'
    FROM cte
    WHERE HasGap = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Asset, @StartDate AS StartDate, StartDate AS EndDate, 'Code10', 'Reason10'
    FROM cte
    WHERE rn = 1
      AND StartDate > @StartDate
  ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Comment: That's amazing thanks man, you really helped me out here.  How would you modify this if you wanted a @StartDate as well?

Comment: `UNION ALL` is much preferred to `UNION`.  `UNION` incurs overhead for removing duplicates.

Comment: I just edited the code a little in order to feature a StartDate as well - please check if this works as required by you. :-)

Comment: if you cannot use LEAD consider use the self join

Comment: Just fixed a glitch I found in my code: I totally forgot about the partitioning by Asset... however, should be correct now.